# Shouldn't the output resistance of a class B amplifier include r_o?

Tags: power-output-stage

[image: Sedra and Smith microelectronics 5th ed, page 937]

If you apply the small signal T model to the picture above, and try to get the output resistance R_out, isn't there a r_o from each emitter to the collectors, which should be in parallel to the r_e resistances from emitter to base?

The output resistance should be (r_en // r_ep // r_on // r_op), no? I've seen in other sources that the output resistance of an AB amplifier is r_en // r_ep, for example:

[image: Lecture slide I found online here: http://pallen.ece.gatech.edu/Academic/ECE_6412/Spring_2004/L060-Push-Pull(2UP).pdf]

This model is wrong, is it not? r_on and r_op should be from the collectors to the emitters, not from base to collector.

Comment: These are actually AB amplifiers, but the small signal models / output resistances are the same.

Comment: But r'e is much much smaller than r'o. So why bother including r'o in the first place?

Comment: In the real world amplifier, Zo formula will be much more complicated than shown.

Comment: Emitter Follower .... Rout = Rb   / hFE + re

Comment: I was thinking r_e was based on emitter current and r_o was based on collector current, which should be the same, but you're right because r_o is based on the early voltage which will be large (say 100V) and r_e is based on the thermal voltage which will be quite small (say 25mv). Ultimately r_e dominates. If you want to submit this as an answer I'll give it to you @G36

Comment: _"This model is wrong, is it not?"_ - _All_ models are wrong - but some are useful.